# What calendar/timekeeping method is used in the Railsea?

Tags: railsea

Is it ever mentioned what calendar the societies of the Railsea use for time-keeping in their local part of the world? Given the setting, I can't imagine that they use the same calendar we're familiar with in the modern world – but is their method of tracking years and seasons (or even the names of any of the months they use) ever touched on in the novel?

I've been looking so far, but haven't had much luck turning anything up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, years, centuries (& seasons).

**Time is measured in seconds.**

> Thanks very much for saving us, Caldera thought. I wish you weren’t about to die. She counted down seconds till impact. Ten, she thought. Nine. Eight.

**Seconds are measured into minutes.**

> “Will you bloody Shroakes stop!” Sham shouted. Caldera hesitated. “Give us five minutes & stop being melodramatic. We’re all coming!”

**Minutes are measured into hours.**

> “The rails everywhere round here are coming off it. Like wax off a candle. It’s going to take hours ‘n’ hours to plot a route around it. We want to be right on the other side.” She pointed.

**Hours are measured into days.**

> “But. See, when I got on that mail-train to come back, after a couple of days, there’s a little train behind us.

**Days are measured into months.**

> “You know what the stakes of this are,” Naphi said. She wasn’t much of a one for speechifying, but she couldn’t not. As her officers had told her, the crew needed to hear something. “We may be at railsea a long time,” the captain said, voice cracking through the tubes. “Months. Years. This hunt will take us far. I am prepared. Will you come with me?” Ooh, nice touch, Sham thought.

**Months are measured into years.**

> “Can’t keep up with the research. We’re years out of date. & what gets us into this line is that we want to think about things other than medicine, sometimes. Which is why I’m not wholly stricken by your variable interest.”

**Years are measured into centuries.**

> He sifted through the papers. “How long you been waiting?” Sham said. “How long ago was the godsquabble? The railway wars?” Years. Centuries. Epochs.

**Seasons pass and are recognised.**

> Clickclick, the captain scrolled. Sham was being driven crazy by her ability to sit without speaking. & on-screen were images of the railsea itself & its islands. Tracks among & through thickets of old trees. A forest, no other word for it, not on any humpback island but part of the railsea itself. **It had been autumn when the shot was taken, & banks of leaves piled up on the rails ahead.**
>
> A desert, flat sand, sparse tracks. Rocks like fangs under the overcast sky. Where, where, had these people been?

---

**Ancient calendars (presumably including our own) have long since been lost to antiquity. The tendency is to describe various *epochs* rather than naming years of events.**

> You wish to know which is the oldest civilisation in the railsea,
> which island state’s records go back furthest, using which calendar?
> What do they tell us about the history of the world, the Lunchtime
> Ages, prehistory, the times before the scattered debris from offhand
> offworld picnicking visitors was added to aeons of salvage? Is it true
> the upsky used to be full of the same birds as now fly the down? & if
> so, what was the point of that?

Comment: @lexible - The place (Railsea) is frequently referred to without the capital letter in the book. Can you please double-check what you're correcting before you fix it wrong.

Comment: [Proper noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun). Where I corrected was where the definite article was used, suggesting a proper geographic designation. (But I take your point about confirming with the source... for stylistic violation of grammar.)

Comment: @Lexible - It's generally a good idea to check a book quote against the actual book before "correcting" it.